# Angular Component Uses Another Component Which Uses an Imported Module - Organization?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module, file-structure

I'm pretty new to Angular, and can't seem to work out how to organize my code properly.

I have a page called BudgetComponent, which belongs to BudgetModule. BudgetComponent displays an accordion list of AccordionItemComponents. I want to use these Accordion Components elsewhere, which is why they're their own component class.

The AccordionItemComponent has an img that when clicked opens a MatDialogue. The MatDialogue contains a reference to an imported module ngx-extended-pdf-viewer (from an online library).

I have created an AccordionItemModule (which I'm not is necessary/correct) to house the corresponding component, but then I'm not sure how to make instances of this in my ngFor.

I'm really struggling to figure out which components should belong to which modules, and how to make all of this work, so that another component (with it's own module like Budget (ie Schedule)), can also reference AccordionItems. I'm not sure if I'm missing necessary routing or export logic, or what...

I have included a diagram to make sure the intended use is clear.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need one common `sharedModule`. In this `sharedModule` you have to define anything like components, directives, pipes and your own models to your app. In your case in `sharedModule` you have to define or import  1. `<app-accordion-item>` 2. `<app-model-component>`  3. `<your-pdf-viewer>`  and export it too.. and then when required just import this `sharedModule` to your needed module and use features of in your own module defined in shared-module..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in the right direction here.

Firstly, export `AccordionItemComponent` like this `exports: [AccordionItemComponent]` in your `AccordionItemModule` class.

Secondly, add `AccordionItemModule` to `imports` in your `BudgetModule` and `ScheduleModule` class since you wish to use `AccordionItemComponent` component in there.

Thirdly, pass data from `Budget` and `Schedule` component to the `Accordion` component by adding it in the html file as follows:

```
<app-accordion-item [data]="accordianData"></app-accordion-item>
```

Fourthly, get data in `AccordionItemComponent` by using `@Input() data;` as a class variable. Now you will have access to the data that is being passed from `Budget` and `Schedule` component.

Finally, loop your `*ngFor` to get the desired result in `accordion-item.component.html`.

To use `Modal` component, add `Modal` module to `imports` and add `Modal` component as `entryComponents: [ModalComponent]` to your `Accordion` module.

Lastly, your `Modal` module should `import` the required module for `ngx-pdf-viewer`.

Comment: I see, thank you! What about the Modal module and ngx-pdf-viewer? Having errors trying to nest those. Currently the Modal is a component with the MatDialogue type. I'm not sure which module should be importing the ngx-pdf-viewer. I've tried in the AccordionItemModule, but then the modal doesn't recognize it?

Comment: Updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: That all makes a lot of sense, and seems so simple now that you've laid it out. Thanks a ton for the clear explanation. Everything is working like a charm, except for one part. I've defined the ngx-pdf-viewer as an import into my modal module, and the modal's html recognizes it (there's no issues in the editor), but the compiler says it's not a recognized component. Any ideas??

Comment: Is it possible that the open dialog calls the component, but not the module?

Comment: It looks like a configuration issue to me. Have you configured the library properly? Try running `npm install` and `ng build` again and see if it gives you any errors. Also, if this opens up as a dialog then you might have to add it to the `entryComponents` of ModalModule. This is the best I could guess without seeing the code.